# Até quando o SOpt será/estara na versão Beta?

Tags: debate, suporte, status-pronto

Até quando o SOpt será/estará na versão Beta?

Qual o quesito para deixar de ser beta?

*Ou SOpt Beta é mesmo o nome e eu não notei?* (Não liguem muito esta questão :))

Comment: Muito interessante sua pergunta, e ela não se aplica só ao SOPt, o codegolf.stackexchange também está em beta a um bom tempo

Comment: Cara, ontem a noite eu estava pensando nisso.

Comment: Pelo que sei o SOpt já poderia se graduar. Porém, um efeito colateral é que muitos usuários iriam perder privilégios, já que a reputação mínima para obtê-los seria bem maior. Dentre outros motivos, acho que isso pesa muito para a equipe do SO, que está dando uma segurada esperando que mais usuários ganhem reputação no site.

Comment: @utluiz se a questão for mesmo esta, então que fique assim, minha reputação é pequena ainda rsrsrsrs